# angularJS how to reload a div by clicking a button or icon?

Tags: html, angularjs, reload, angularjs-ng-include

How can I reload a div like "`<div id={{tab.index}}div  ng-include="tab.template" ></div>`" by clicking a button?

Comment: which div and what u mean by reloading , please brief us properly and what u need to achieve

Comment: there are some tabs in my page, when I click on the tab page, it switch to this page,each page is included by a div<div ng-include="tab.template" ></div> ,the problem is that I want to refresh one of the page by clicking a button